# Send post data using curl and write it into file

Tags: php, curl

I have pretty simple PHP code to send post data using curl and write it to a file. But all I get is an empty array. I am sending data from one domain to another and both domains are run by me.  I tried using examples of similar posts at StackOverflow but always get an empty array.

curl function :

```
function run()
    {
        $serverData['php']          = PHP_VERSION;
        $serverData['url']          = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
    
        $ch = curl_init('https://test.com/tracking/');
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $serverData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

        curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

Receive post data:

```
$response = $_POST['url']." ".$_POST['php']; 
        $fp = fopen('vardump.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, serialize($response));
        fclose($fp);
        var_dump($response);
```

Comment: What specifically do you mean by "an empty array". What exactly is the output of `var_dump($response);`? I note that in the client-side code you write `$response = curl_exec($ch);` but you never do anything to output that response, so I don't know how you can be seeing the result actually. And what exactly is in your file? Neither var_dump or serialize() outputs an array so it's a bit unclear what you mean. Are you saying the `$_POST` array is empty? What does `var_dump($_POST);` output?

Comment: What I mean by an empty array is that there is nothing in it. What I get in the file is `s:1:" ";` meaning it writes in only a blank space. 
`var_dump($_POST);`  gets me - > `array(0) { }`

Comment: All was working from the beginning, the problem was that I reloaded the tracker page after the curl sends data and it forced the file to write an empty array.  I can say I am not the smartest...

Comment: It happens to us all, glad you resolved it